# How to stack in-line-block elements

Tags: html, layout, css-float, css

Is it possible to stack in-line-block elements?

I have a DIV which I want the elements inside it (h1 and P) to be centred. So I set the DIV to text-align centre and initally set the H1 and P tag to inline-blocks.respectively.

The idea was to display the two elements (H1 and P) as in-line-block elements so content is centred and  a transparent png shows in the background for the length of the text.

But the problem I have is that having elements as inline-blocks means they will appears next to each other (I don't want this to happen), so I set the P tag as block element but it's resulting in the transparent png being as wide.

[image]

```
HTML:
<div id="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12" id="hero-text">
                    <h2>Heading line</h2>
                    <p>Paragraph line goes here</p>                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

CSS

#hero {
height: 435px;
width: 100%;
background: url(../img/hero-image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
background-color: #999;
position: relative;
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: 3px solid #E6E6E6;
}


#hero-text {
position: absolute;
top: 33%;
text-align: center;
}

#hero h2 {
font-size: 4em;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 50px;
padding-top: 10px;
background: url(../img/bg-heading.png) repeat;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 20px;
}

#hero p {
font-size: 2em;
line-height: 30px;
display: block;
background: url(../img/bg-heading.png) repeat;
padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The whole point of inline blocks is to make them flow inline. If you want the blocks to stack, don't use inline-block.

Comment: I get the point of inline blocks. I suppose am looking for a display setting that combines some properties of inline blocks (so transparent png is only as as long the text and to centre within the div) and blocks (so that they stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually tougher to solve than I originally thought. I could find two options for you. If you don't want to change your markup:

---

1. Give both #hero h2 and #hero p display:inline-block, and give them widths so that their combined width is greater than 100%. They both can be width:51%, or one can be wider than the other, just as long as their total is more than the width of the parent. This will cause the p to break to a new line. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cjDiH OR

2.If you want their widths to be fluid, I'd add an element in between the h2 and p that is display:block. I added hr, then took away its margin, padding and border to make it not visible other than to cause the line break. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AGDti

Comment: Thanks.First option causes the transparent png to expand to the full width of the H1 or P tags where as I want the transparent png to be only as wide as the length of the text. The second options works (although purist may object to using html elements purely for presentation purposes). I will accept this answer if nothing else comes through. Thanks again.

Comment: Extra markup like this makes me cringe as well. I really can't think of a way to avoid it, though, if you want to use inline-block (so you can take advantage of the text-align:center trick) and you don't want to give explicit widths to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I see you figured out out to get them to stack like in your screenshot.

Now,

try adding `width: auto;` to `#hero p` in your css.

Comment: sorry, setting the width to auto doesn't work. the p tag lines up with the h2.